# Where should I place an XSD file to use for JAXB code gen and for XML validation

Tags: java, xml, maven, xsd, jaxb

I have created an XSD file in my Java project that defines a user-editable input file (for illustration, let's say the XSD is called userinput.xsd and the user-editable file is userinput.xml).  When the program runs, it uses JAXB to validate that the user has not made any mistakes in the XML file as it unmarshalls the file into a DOM.

I have structured my project using the [Maven Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html) and generated the JAXB object factory and other classes using xjc, placing them in a directory called /src/main/java/my/name/space/generated/userinput (to match the name of the XSD).

I have placed the XSD file in /src/main/resources.

When I package my jar file, the file is in the root of the jar and I can refer to it in the Java code as follows (note in particular the resource mentioned in line 4):

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance("my.name.space.generated.userinput");
Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
SchemaFactory schemaFactory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(getClass().getResource("/userinput.xsd"));
unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
JAXBElement<?> userinputType = (JAXBElement<?>) unmarshaller.unmarshal(new FileInputStream("userinput.xml"));
```

This works but it does not seem right as it means if I want to scale to multiple input files, I could end up with many .xsd files both in the resources directory in my source control and in the root of the jar file.

Also when I run the program from my IDE rather than from the packaged jar, I have to change the fourth statement to:

```
Schema schema = schemaFactory.newSchema(getClass().getResource("src/main/resources/userinput.xsd"));
```

Where should I put the XSD file (a) in my source control (i.e., the Maven structure) and (b) in my jar file?  [Note: Running xjc through my IDE puts it in the .../generated/userinput directory but Maven then ignores it when packaging.]

I'm looking for an answer that indicates that there is some sort of common methodology, so would like a reference if possible.  If this is currently an unspecified choice left to the developer, then please say so (preferably referenced) as I understand that stackoverflow is not the place to collect opinions.

Comment: An XML Schema file is a resource like many others. It may be a resource on the web. Other than this, it may be a resource defining an interface between applications: then it should be in a place available to all. If it is bundled with a Java library, a jar may be the right place.

Comment: I realise my question is ambiguous. I am asking which particular directory within the source code and which (maybe different) directory within the jar file should the XSD file be placed to be consistent with what others will expect.  Is it a free-for-all decision or is there something like the Maven standard directory layout that can be used as a guide?

Comment: Within Eclipse, a project usually contains subdirectories src, bin, resources. Within a jar, an .xsd would be meant to be accessed by your own SW, so there's no "others expect", I guess. I've seen xsd files in META-INF or in some package, along with .class, or below ./src.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default layout for [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin) is to put schemas in `src/main/resources`. Your schema `schema.xsd` is then available as resource as `getClass().getResource("/schema.xsd")`.
Some people use `src/main/schemas` or `src/main/xsd`. But if you want to use schemas as resources, better use the default.

I don't see why this "does not seem right". What exactly is the problem? Many files in the version control? Many files in a JAR? Why is that a problem?

If you want to structure and modularize, compile your schemas separately, in own Maven modules. I normally prefer one module per specification/version (see the [ogc-schemas](https://github.com/highsource/ogc-schemas) project, for instance.

If you need to do `getClass().getResource("src/main/resources/userinput.xsd")` in IDE, this is a sign that you have a wrong project configuration in the IDE. Resources should be copied/seen as a part of the classpath so just `/userinput.xsd` is supposed to work. This does not mean `src/main/resources` is a wrong place, it means your project is not correctly configured.

If you're using Maven, don't rely on IDE for code generation. Code generation is a part of the build process. Use a Maven plugin for schema compilation.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of [maven-jaxb2-plugin](/questions/tagged/maven-jaxb2-plugin) and also of the OGC Schemas project mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, lexicore, this is a great answer!  It turned out that it was my project configuration within the IDE that was wrong.  I don't know what was wrong because when I retested with the resource as "/userinput.xsd" it worked in the IDE today.  I must have gone through a series of steps that eventually made it work although I don't know what they were.

Comment: I accidentally pressed Enter and didn't finish my comment ... here's the rest.  I have now started using the maven-jaxb2-plugin which has made the project much neater - the "mvn package" goal does everything. I thought it was a problem to have many XSD files in /src/main/resources because it would get cluttered. Your suggestion of separating into multiple jars solves that as well.